# ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer Custom Renderer

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, model-view-viewmodel

My 1 Service have only 1 layer with year wise archive data. Like it have same geometries at different year along with some addon in another year.

I want to use this Dynamic layer for representing the geoms on map yearwise with different symbols [Polyline] when user choose year. I m using MVVM Light, Silverlight. I do what ever but not able to change the rendering of Layer.

I crate **`ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`** when User click on check box and create the layer. Then add to `LayersCollection`. once it initialize then I add Rendere. But still no hope. Can any one help me?

```py
 public void ProjectLayer(ref HpmsMapLayerModel lyr, ref HpmsBaseEsriMapViewModel baseVm,bool isDynamic)
    {
        currentProjection = null;
        currentProjection = lyr;
        BaseVm = baseVm;
        ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer mapLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer();

        mapLayer.Url = lyr.Url;
        mapLayer.ID = lyr.Id;
        mapLayer.DisableClientCaching = true;
        LayerInfo linf = new LayerInfo();
        linf.ID = 0;
        linf.SubLayerIds = new int[]{0};
        linf.DefaultVisibility = false;

      DynamicLayerInfoCollection  dyLyInfColx= mapLayer.CreateDynamicLayerInfosFromLayerInfos();
         dyLyInfColx = new DynamicLayerInfoCollection();

          BaseMapVM.Layers.Add(mapLayer);
        mapLayer.Initialized+=mapLayer_Initialized;
        GetFeatures("HPMSYEAR='" + 2013 + "'", lyr, baseVm);

    }

    private void mapLayer_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rlyr = sender as ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer;
        var lyr = BaseMapVM.Layers.Where(L => L.ID == rlyr.ID).FirstOrDefault() as ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer;
        lyr.Layers[0].DefaultVisibility = false;
        DynamicLayerInfo layer1 = new DynamicLayerInfo();
        layer1.ID = 0;
        LayerMapSource lms =  new LayerMapSource();
        lms.MapLayerID = 4;
        layer1.Source = lms;
        DynamicLayerInfoCollection dyLyInfColx = lyr.CreateDynamicLayerInfosFromLayerInfos();
        dyLyInfColx.Add(layer1);

        lyr.DynamicLayerInfos = dyLyInfColx;

        LayerDefinition ldef = new LayerDefinition();
        ldef.LayerID = 0;
        string whereClse = "HPMSYEAR='" +2013+"'";
        ldef.Definition = whereClse;
        ObservableCollection<LayerDefinition> layerDrfins = new ObservableCollection<LayerDefinition>();
        layerDrfins.Add(ldef);
        lyr.LayerDefinitions = layerDrfins;

        LayerDrawingOptions ldrOpns = new LayerDrawingOptions();
        ldrOpns.LayerID = 0;
        UniqueValueRenderer myUniqueValueRenderer = new UniqueValueRenderer();
        myUniqueValueRenderer.Field = "HPMSYEAR";
        UniqueValueInfo myUniqueValueInfo1 = new UniqueValueInfo();
        myUniqueValueInfo1.Value = 2013;
        //SimpleFillSymbol mySimpleFillSymbol1 = 
        //    new SimpleFillSymbol();
        SimpleLineSymbol smp = new SimpleLineSymbol();
        smp.Color = BrushConstants.Green; // BrushConstants.DefaultBrushes[colorIndex];
        smp.Width = 5;
        myUniqueValueInfo1.Symbol = smp;
        myUniqueValueRenderer.Infos.Add(myUniqueValueInfo1);
        ldrOpns.Renderer = myUniqueValueRenderer;

        LayerDrawingOptionsCollection ldoc = new LayerDrawingOptionsCollection();
        ldoc.Add(ldrOpns);
        lyr.LayerDrawingOptions = ldoc;
        ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer rLyr = null;
        rLyr = BaseMapVM.Layers.Where(L => L.ID == lyr.ID).FirstOrDefault() as ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer;
        if (rLyr != null)
        {
           // BaseMapVM.Layers.Remove(rLyr);
           // BaseMapVM.Layers.Add(lyr);
            lyr.Refresh();
        }

        var b = e;
    }
```

When User Click on Check Box `HpmsMapLayerModel` class contains the URL, Name, Id etc information and I `HpmsBaseEsriMapViewModel` contains the Map Object etc.

What I m doing wrong. I m not able to figure out. All the time layer get loaded with full data. Along with predefined rendere which is of Pink Color.

Answer (score 1):

Here is What I did :

1. So late I figure out My Services don't have capability of Allow per request modification of layer order and symbology. I was not getting option links at service for 
   Dynamic Legend & Dynamic All Layers change options in REST service exposed. Service change request to Admin.
2. In my Code

```py
    public void ProjectLayer(ref HpMapLayerModel lyr, ref HpBaseEsriMapViewModel baseVm,bool isDynamic)
    {
        currentProjection = null;
        currentProjection = lyr;
        BaseVm = baseVm;
        ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer mapLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer();            
        mapLayer.Url = lyr.Url;
        mapLayer.ID = lyr.Id;
        mapLayer.DisableClientCaching = true;
        LayerInfo linf = new LayerInfo();
        linf.ID = 0;
        linf.SubLayerIds = new int[]{0};
        linf.DefaultVisibility = false;
        BaseMapVM.Layers.Add(mapLayer);
        mapLayer.Initialized+=mapLayer_Initialized;

    }

    private void mapLayer_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnChangeGeomColorAsPerLayer(null);
    }
    GenerateRendererTask generateRendererTask;
    private void OnChangeGeomColorAsPerLayer(object obj)
    {
        generateRendererTask = new GenerateRendererTask();
        generateRendererTask.Url = currentProjection.Url+"/0";
        generateRendererTask.ExecuteCompleted += generateRendererTask_ExecuteCompleted;
        generateRendererTask.Failed += generateRendererTask_Failed;

        GenerateRendererParameters rendererParams = ConditionalLoadForRenderer();
        generateRendererTask.ExecuteAsync(rendererParams, rendererParams.Where);
    }

    public GenerateRendererParameters ConditionalLoadForRenderer()
    {
        GenerateRendererParameters rendererParams=null;
        if (currentProjection != null)
        {
            if (currentProjection.IsItemLayer)
            {
                if (!currentProjection.IsArchiveLayer)
                {
                    UniqueValueDefinition uniqueValueDefinition = new UniqueValueDefinition()
                    {
                        Fields = new List<string>() { "ITEMID" }
                    };

                    uniqueValueDefinition.ColorRamps.Add(new ColorRamp()
                    {
                        From = (currentProjection.DefaultBrush as SolidColorBrush).Color,
                        To = (currentProjection.DefaultBrush as SolidColorBrush).Color,
                        Algorithm = Algorithm.LabLChAlgorithm
                    });
                     rendererParams = new GenerateRendererParameters()
                    {
                        ClassificationDefinition = uniqueValueDefinition,
                        Where = "ITEMID IN (" + currentProjection.Itemm.Itemno + ")"
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    UniqueValueDefinition uniqueValueDefinition = new UniqueValueDefinition()
                    {
                        Fields = new List<string>() { "ITEMID", "YEAR" }
                    };

                    uniqueValueDefinition.ColorRamps.Add(new ColorRamp()
                    {
                        From = (currentProjection.DefaultBrush as SolidColorBrush).Color,
                        To = (currentProjection.DefaultBrush as SolidColorBrush).Color,
                        Algorithm = Algorithm.LabLChAlgorithm
                    });

                     rendererParams = new GenerateRendererParameters()
                    {
                        ClassificationDefinition = uniqueValueDefinition,
                        Where = "ITEMID IN (" + currentProjection.Itemm.Itemno + ") AND YEAR IN (" + currentProjection.LayerYear + ")"
                    };
                }
            }
            else
            {
             if(BaseVm.Module.Modulename.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("ROUTES") ||
                 BaseVm.Module.Modulename.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("ROUTE"))
             {
                 ConditionalLoadForRoutes();
             }   
            }                
        }
        return rendererParams; 
    }
```

I have to build 100's of layer as per ITEMNO while table contains variable ITems so Service contains all geometries in it.

Comment: For Colors Use these link
//http://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/translating-c-color-to-silverlight-color/
//http://lotsacode.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/translating-c-brushes-to-silverlight-brushes/